# How to filter Mailgun logs/messages by message id

Tags: php, mailgun

I am using mailgun to send emails, and in response mailgun sends a message id which I save in the database to get logs in crone.

But I did not find any method to get the log of a single email by sending message its id; I can only see that I can send a range of them or a total limit. But I want to send a single message id and get only the response of that message.

I am using PHP events.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

# Instantiate the client.
$mgClient    = Mailgun::create('PRIVATE_API_KEY', 'https://API_HOSTNAME');
$domain      = 'mydomainname';
$queryString = array(
    'message-id'    => '20130812164300.28108.52546@samples.mailgun.org'
);

# Issue the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->events()->get($domain, $queryString);

print_r($result );
```